# NodeJS via PowerShell, fs.open, fs.writeFile, etc can't create new file

Tags: node.js

I created a createFile.js file with my fav text editor and saved it.  From a PowerShell command line (with Administrator privileges), I'm running `node .\createFile.js` and getting the error message `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ProgramData\BigObject File - 2023-5-15_15:37:4.json'`.  Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var workingDir = "C:\\ProgramData\\";
var bigObj = {
    "items": []
};
var data = JSON.stringify(bigObj);
now = new Date();
fn = workingDir + 'BigObject File - ' + now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate() + '_';
fn += now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds() + '.json';
fs.writeFile(fn, data, (err)=> {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File saved: '+fn);
});
```

Every bit of NodeJS documentation says I should be able to use fs.open or fs.writeFile to create a new file, but I'm still getting the above error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does C:\ProgramData\ exist?

Comment: The spaces may be the problem

Comment: C:\ProgramData\ does exist.  I was executing the .js file in that directory.  I tried removing the spaces from the filename, but it still fails:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ProgramData\AnomalyDetectionSettings_-_2023-5-16_17:21:22.json'